# bbcode_parser wont allow linebreaks

Tags: php, bbcode

```
function bb_parse($string, $tags = 'b|i|u|quote|url|img|youtube|user') {
    $replacement = 0;
    while (preg_match_all('`\[('.$tags.')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]`', $string, $matches)) foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
        list($tag, $param, $innertext) = array($matches[1][$key], $matches[2][$key], $matches[3][$key]);
        switch ($tag) {
            case 'b': $replacement = '<strong>'.$innertext.'</strong>'; break;
            case 'i': $replacement = '<em>'.$innertext.'</em>'; break;
            case 'u': $replacement = '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">'.$innertext.'</span>'; break;
            case 'quote': $replacement = '<div class="quote"><div class="quote-author">'.($param ? 'Quote by: '.$param : 'Quote').'</div>'.$innertext.'</div>'; break;
            case 'url': $replacement = '<a href="'.($param ? $param : $innertext).'">'.$innertext.'</a>'; break;
            case 'user': $replacement = '<a href="'.url('user/'.($param ? $param : $innertext)).'">'.$innertext.'</a>'; break;
            case 'img': $replacement = '<img src="'.$innertext.'" style="max-width: 640px;"/>'; break;
            case 'youtube':
            $videourl = parse_url($innertext);
            parse_str($videourl['query'], $videoquery);
            if (strpos($videourl['host'], 'youtube.com') !== FALSE) $replacement = '<div><iframe width="755" height="425" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoquery['v'].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
            break;
        }
        $string = str_replace($match, $replacement, $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

If i use [quote] with linebreaks for example, it will output this:

```
[quote]This is {LINEBREAK}
a test[/quote]
```

And not this as supposed to

```
<div class="quote"><div class="quote-author">Quote</div>This is {LINEBREAK}
a test</div>
```

Anyone have a idea?

Comment: Try adding a `s` modifier to your regex ([`PCRE_DOTALL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).

Comment: Change the expression string to `'#\[('.$tags.')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]#s'` - note the `s` on the very end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `s` modifier on your RegEx to signal 'single line mode'. The dot (`.`) doesn't match new line characters by default. Using the `s` modifier, it does.

```
preg_match_all('`\[('.$tags.')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]`s', $string, $matches)
```